# Input language and keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, language-support

I am not very familiar with Ubuntu and most time I am using Windows. So I want to make this environments more alike.
In Windows I have such things like input language and keyboard layout.

[image]

So I can assign more than one layout to each language and use another key combination to switch layouts inside one language.

For example I have such configuration with approx. using time.

English language:

- US layout - 40%
- US intl layout - 5%

Ukrainian language:

- RUS layout - 35%
- UKR layout - 20%

Basically I have cyrillic and latin language set and layouts inside them. I can switch between this sets with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and switch layouts with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Example (not mine, taken from Google):

[image]

Any way to do such thing on Linux without wasting hours to make patch for keyboard layout manager?

Comment: Haven't looked hard enough to see if it is supported out of box, but I think that at least it can be done with 'gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current', evrouter and a bash script. (not saying that it actually should be done like that)

Comment: When you say "assign more than one layout to each language", do you mean that you have a different setup of available keyboard layouts depending on which display language you are using?

Answer (score 1):

If you open "System Settings", and choose "Text Entry", you will have an option to add more then one keyboard language. You also have the option to assign a shortcut to change the language on the fly, and show a language switch in the notification area.

AFAIK then you cannot add a language, and add different layouts to that language in Ubuntu. Instead you add languages (each have their own layout) and just switch between those.

Ie. I can add a language "English (US)", and another language "English (US International)" and just switch between those two, they will not be "grouped" but you can define the order they switch.

Comment: How is this supposed to help to get a solution for initial question? You basically just answered - No, you can't. That's not a solution.