# System ignore selected keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

After my experiments with keyboard layots (to achieve [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609339/input-language-and-keyboard-layout) thing) I lost ability to switch them. Only available layout is En(us). I can switch it and icon in top bar changes but it not affects to real layout.

I have made this script to recover cirillic scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a layout_set=('us' 'ru(winkeys)' 'ua(winkeys)');

curr_layout=`setxkbmap -query | grep "layout" | awk '{print $2}'`;

layout_count=${#layout_set[@]};
for (( i=0; i<$layout_count; i++ ));
do
  if [ ${layout_set[$i]} == $curr_layout ]
  then
    cur_layout_num=$i;
  fi
done

next_layout_num=$(($cur_layout_num + 1));

if [ $next_layout_num -eq $layout_count ]
then
  next_layout_num=0;
fi

setxkbmap -layout ${layout_set[$next_layout_num]};
```

It works well, but Ubuntu doesn't allow me to assign it to Ctrl+Shift hotkey and I should use another (Super+Space). Also I can't display current layout at top bar.

So, can anybody help me to fix my problem or al least improve my script? With guest account I have no problems but I think creating new user account is not good solution.