# Keyboard layout is ignored

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, 16.04, language-support

I installed Ubuntu 16.04. At first I only had English keyboard. Then I added Lithuanian. But when I change layout, it still writes as keyboard is using English layout. When I open current keyboard layout, I can see it is changed. But when I type it just ignores it. For example, entering numbers (The ones that are below F1, F2 etc. keys) should output Lithuanian letters, but it still outputs numbers.

Also for some reason key combinations do not change keyboard layout, I can only change by clicking on language icon and selecting language.

P.S. it seems someone has similar problem here [System ignore selected keyboard layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610423/system-ignore-selected-keyboard-layout). Though that one was caused by messing some settings. But I did not change anything, I just added additional keyboard layout.

Comment: Do you see the input source indicator in the menu bar? Try to switch a couple of times between English and Lithuanian from the input source menu and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes I see it. I can change by selecting with a mouse only, though I can see icon change language, but when I type, it ignores layout that I changed to .

Comment: What if you first open the window where you want to type something, and switch to Lithuanian immediately before typing?

Comment: After couple system auto updates, this problem disappeared. Probably was some sort of bug.